# Demonstration of AI-powered Mario collecting lots of coins?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, game-ai, atari-games

As part of a talk I'm giving, I'd like to show one of the many videos on YouTube where an AI is playing Mario, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scLTbin8FiQ&t=69s). What bothers me though is that the AI is trying to complete the level as quickly as possible, without trying to collect lots of coins. I believe it's known as "speed run" in the gaming world, which is fine and well, but I think most people expect Mario to be collecting lots of coins and mushrooms.

**Are you familiar with a video of an AI-powered Mario that does collect a lot of coins and mushrooms?**

If not, maybe you know a different video of a similarly popular video game where the AI does try to get lots of points and not just do a speed run?